# What is the right way to use written numbers and numerals in scientific writing?

Tags: numbers

I am preparing a manuscript for a scientific journal. I want to write "We injected cells into the tumor-bearing mice eleven days later. Mice were sacrificed four days after the transfer of cells. " A native speaker edits it into "We injected cells into the tumor-bearing mice 11 days later. Mice were sacrificed four days after the transfer of cells."

Is there a reason for this change of "eleven" to "11", but keep "four days" unchanged? Does it look odd if we mix written numbers and numerals in scientific writing?

Comment: What do the style guidelines for the journal say?

Comment: Were you offered [Is it acceptable to use digit and word form of numbers in the same sentence/paragraph?](/q/21163) Does that answer this question? If it doesn't, could you edit your question to elicit the information you need?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a style guide for the journal? For example, the Guardian (a British daily newspaper) has a style guide [here](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a). This is what is says for "numbers":

> Spell out from one to nine; numerals from 10 to 999,999; thereafter
> use m, bn or tn for sums of money, quantities or inanimate objects in
> copy, eg 5m tonnes of coal, 30bn doses of vaccine, £50tn; but million
> or billion for people or animals, eg 1 million people, 25 million
> rabbits, the world population is 7 billion, etc; in headlines always
> use m, bn or tn.

So the advice is, consult the journal's style guide. If there's no style guide, maybe consult one for a similar publication and stick to it. The main thing is to be consistent.